# Overlay Panel shows arrow on the wrong position (primeng)

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have a p-table and I am using a p-overlaypanel to filter. The problem is that the overlaypanel shows the arrow wrong.The arrow appears on the right and I want it to appear on the left. See the image

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYxWz.png)

In this image, the overlaypanel must be associated with the row called username.

This is my code HTML of span

```
   <span class="filter-button" *ngIf="col.filter">
              <p-button id={{col.field}} styleClass="no-bg-button" icon="fas fa-filter"
                [style]="{'padding':0, 'width': '20px', 'height': '20px'}" (click)="filter($event, col.field)">
              </p-button>
   </span>
```

And this is the code of overlay:

```
 <p-overlayPanel #filterOverlay id="overlay">
  <input [(ngModel)]="filterInput" pInputText type="text"
    (input)="incTable.filter($event.target.value, filterField, 'contains')" placeholder=""/>
 </p-overlayPanel>
```

And this is my code in javascript:

```
filter(event: Event, field: string) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  this._incTable.reset();
  this.filterField = field;
  this.filterInput = '';
  this.filterOverlay.toggle(event);
}
```

When I click in the span, the overlaypanel appears. The solution of setting a width to the table or changing the css doesn't work for me. Any solution?

- Version Angular: 8.2.14
- Version PrimeNG: 8.1.1

Answer (score 1):

[Kumbirai Bodzo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67194053), with the double-quotation marks around the value, didn't work for me. I found that you don't need those at all. Just do:

```
appendTo='body'
```

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
[appendTo]="'body'"
```